# Can I use the Ubuntu SDK Preview in Linux Mint?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

Can I use [Linux Mint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint) to develop applications for [Ubuntu Touch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Touch) with the Ubuntu SDK preview?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu sdk is open source , and ubuntu and mint uses same package management system . So therectically it is possible to install ubuntu sdk in linux mint . But it is not officially supported